# Unable to login into Jira using ruby with Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I am working on automating jira restore process using Watir. First step was to launch a FF window and that I have achieved via:

```
require "Watir"
test_site="http://jira:8080"
browser=Watir::Browser.new :firefox 
browser.goto test_site
```

Next, is to login into Jira. And, this is where I am unable to get it done

[Jiralogin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIxvk.png)

In the above image, html code from Jira login form is shared. I have tried entering the text in the "input" attribute via xpath, css and custom attributes. However, every time I am getting error similar to:

```
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::HTMLElement: located: false; {:xpath=>"//input[@id='#login-form-username.text.medium-field']"}> to be located. Maybe look in an iframe?
```

Comment: What is the code you are using to find/set the text field element? The error message has a very strange XPath in it - "//input[@id='#login-form-username.text.medium-field']". It seems like a mash up between a CSS-locator and XPath.

Comment: Hi Justin, When jira login page is launched, control by default is going into the text field against username. So, not using any specific code to find/set the text field.

Comment: Did you look to see if the element is inside an IFrame like the error suggested it might be?

Comment: @titusfortner...Thank you. Your pointer helped me in getting it through. It was indeed in iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing xpath and css locators here and you are not writing the correct css path either. Complete mix is happening,

Try this

```
b.text_field(id: 'login-form-username').set 'content'
```

Or if you want to go by xpath then

```
b.text_field(xpath: "//input[@id='login-form-username']").set 'content'
```

Of if you want to go by css then

```
b.text_field(css: "#login-form-username").set 'content'
```

Remember xpath and css are not needed when you have id. When you are in need of locating the element from the parent node or from the adjacent node, then you can go to use xpath but that is also completely not necessary in WATIR, WATIR provides you the simple subsequent function call to locate the right element.

Comment: Thanks, Raj for your reply. Well, though I have already tried your suggested answers, I again went for it. For b.text_field(id: 'login-form-username').set 'content', I am getting below error:                                                                                  `rescue in element_call': timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::TextField: located: false; {:id=>"login-form-username", :tag_name=>"input"}> to be located. Maybe look in an iframe? (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)